# Proving sequence limit using Inductive reasoning

Tags: calculus

I have **positive** sequence called $a_n$
which applies to:
$$a_{n+1} \le \frac{a_n - a_n^2}{2}$$
I want to use Inductive reasoning so I tried to show that
$$a_n < \frac{1}{n}$$
But I didnt succeed in it, how should I approach it?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need $0 \le a_1 \le 1 = \frac11$ as otherwise $a_2$ would be negative.

You can then show that  $a_{n+1} \le \frac{a_n }{2} \le \frac{n}{n+1}a_n$ and so by induction $a_n \le \frac1n$.  Or you could show by induction $a_n \le \frac{2}{2^n}$.

Either will give you a sequence limit of $0$.